# Ruby on Rails activemerchant.rb require error even after installing activemerchant and mechanize (2.5.1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activemerchant

Complete error:

```
.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activemerchant-1.9.4/lib/active_merchant.rb:29:in `require': cannot load such file -- active_support/core_ext/class/inheritable_attributes (LoadError)
```

Hi I am first time trying to use activemerchant. Even after gem install and bundle install if I run any command it give me the same error.

My bundle install command gives me a big list including

```
Using activemerchant (1.9.4)  
Using mechanize (2.5.1)
```

My Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'activemerchant'
gem 'mechanize'
...............# more gems
```

What can be the problem and how to solve it. I am new to Ruby so maybe its an idiot question but I am stuck with it.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is about a missing [`activesupport` gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/activesupport)

When you run `bundle install` or `gem install activemerchant` it downloads one version of `activesupport` gem. Make sure you have a compatible version of `activesupport`gem in your installation.

[`activemerchant gem version 1.9.4`](http://rubygems.org/gems/activemerchant/versions/1.9.4) is dependent on `activesupport gem version >= 2.3.2.`

Quite likely that higher versions of `activesupport` gem is not supported by this version of `activemerchant` gem.